# Find Lagrangian function of a system

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Let P be a point of mass m free to move on the surface of a smooth paraboloid $x^2 + y^2 = z$. An ideal spring of constant factor characteristic k connects the point P with the Focus of the paraboloid:

The question is to find the Lagrangian function of the system.

Of course we know that L = T - V where T is the kinetic energy and V is the potential, so I tried to compute first T and then V.

P is free to move only on the paraboloid so its coordinates are $P=(x,y,x^2 + y^2)$;

The kinetic energy is $T=\frac{1}{2}m$$||\frac{dP}{dt}||^2$, while the potential is $V=mg(x^2+y^2)$ + $\frac{1}{2}k$$||P-F||^2$ where F is the Focus of the paraboloid $F=(0,0,\frac{1}{4})$.

Is it correct? I feel it is not but I can't find my mistake so a help would be very useful;

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your degrees of freedom first, so you may deal with an unconstraint motion. In the cylindrical coordinates your constrain reads $z = \alpha r^2$ (i included the inverse length $\alpha$ for dimensionality reasons, since otherwise your $z$ has the deimension length$^2$), so the range of your motion is parametrized via
$$[x,y,z](r,\phi) = [r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi),\alpha r^2]$$
Where $r$ and $\phi$ are time dependent. In terms of these new degree of freedom the potential reads
$$V(r,\phi) = -mg\alpha r^2 + \frac{k}{2}(r^2+(\alpha r^2 - \frac{1}{4} )^2)$$
and the kinetic energy
$$T = \frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2+4\alpha^2 r^2\dot{r}^2)$$
Now you may apply the Lagrange-formalism wrt. your new coordinates $r$ and $\phi$.

Comment: So you are saying that I made no mistakes but my method is not the smartest one because with cylindrical coordinates the computations is way more easier?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. You should allways pick coordinates which incorporate any holonomic constrains, as in this case the limitation of movement to the parabola. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints

Comment: Infact you way even stick with cartesian coordinates, but you have to include the constrain by using the coordinates $[x,y,z](x,y) = [x,y,\alpha(x^2+y^2)]$. I dont know if this actually renders the equations any easier, but you may check :)

Comment: I just see, that i somewhat misread your question, you actually use the constraint. So your method seems fine!